# Does Google Analytics affect performance in Android?

Tags: android, performance, google-analytics

There is lots of Google Analytics track point in my android code, will it will affect the app's performance? I knew the GA is async, but there are hundreds of track points in my app, so not sure if I should add GA point more carefully in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance impact in this case would mainly depend on IO operations and not on how much tracking points are being added.

As the app collects GA data, that data is added to a queue and periodically dispatched to GA. Periodic dispatch may occur either when your app is running in  foreground or background.

The default dispatch period is 30 minutes but you can provide your own interval in seconds by using "ga_dispatchPeriod" parameter in analytics.xml file, or by calling setDispatchPeriod(int dispatchPeriodInSeconds)

e.g. 60 (in analytics.xml)
GAServiceManager.getInstance().setDispatchPeriod(60); (in code)

Comment: Btw the time provided in setDispatchPeriod takes the time in seconds not minutes so setDispatchPeriod(60) would do dispatching every minute. That is not optimal for battery power consumption as it might potentially keep the mobile radio on hi power for most of the time (radio takes a while to transition between power levels and once woken up will stay up for long time)

Answer (score 1):

The Google analytics SDK sends HTTP Gets or posts (I cant remember which) to Google.   It doesn't wait for a response from the server mainly because the server doesn't return much of one.

It may require a tad more band width to send all these calls.  I cant see it slowing your app down.

Comment: Thanks. However, I will adapt Scorpian's answer since it's the first one.